# How to save table output from Stata's pstest

Tags: save, stata, propensity-score-matching

## How to save table output from Stata's pstest

I want to save the output from Stata's `pstest` command with the option `both` after running `psmatch2`. I use `pstest` in a loop that produces hundreds of tables so copying and pasting individual tables from the screen isn't practical. I've seen this question asked [elsewhere](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1616207-how-to-save-table-from-pstest-command), but I haven't seen a workable solution. `putdocx` does not work to the best of my knowledge.

### My question

My solution below works if the options logit, k-nearest neighbour matching (where k = 5), Abadie and Imbens standard errors, average treatment effects and common support are chosen for `psmatch2` (`logit n(5) ai(5) ate common`) and `both` is the option chosen for the subsequent pstest command, like so `pstest, both atu`. Is there a better, more flexible solution that doesn't require re-writing my code if any of these options change?

To be clear, I'm not looking for anyone to edit my code. My solution works but is long and difficult to revise if different options are specified. A better answer would be simpler, much shorter, and flexible enough to show results when different options are chosen. A solution using `putdocx` would be ideal.

### A suggestion

If it is possible, I would suggest that Stata consider requiring authors of packages to make any output to the screen retrievable in some way, perhaps using `return list` or `ereturn list`. Only the last table produced using pstest can be retrieved this way. I believe, pstest saves the output in the first of two tables in temporary memory, which is lost when the second table is created. Output from the second is available to users via `return list`. If I am mistaken about this, please let me know.

### My solution, so far

This code works, but it is more of a workaround than a solution. In the absence of something better, I hope it will help anyone in a bind similar to the one in which I found myself.

```
* Most of this code is from the pstest.ado by Leuven and Sianesi (2003)
clear all
set more off

* Define the program to generate output from the Stata command pstest

cap program drop pstest_tab
program define pstest_tables
    args exog atu
    
    /* _weight is conditional on ATU option */
    qui replace  _weight = _support if _treated==0
    
    local i = 0
    local cont_cnt = 0     /* counting continuous vars */
    local cont_varbef = 0  /* counting continuous vars w/ excessive var ratio*/
    local cont_varaft = 0  
    
    qui g _bias0 = .
    qui g _biasm = .
    qui g sumbias = .
    qui g sumbias0 = .
    
    scalar wd_num = `:word count `exog''
    mat A = J(wd_num,13,.)
    mat R = J(1,16,.)
    
    qui count if _treated==1 & esample==1
    scalar Flowu  = invF(r(N)-1, r(N)-1, 0.025)
    scalar Fhighu = invF(r(N)-1, r(N)-1, 0.975)

    qui count if _treated==1 & _support==1 & esample==1
    scalar Flowm  = invF(r(N)-1, r(N)-1, 0.025)
    scalar Fhighm = invF(r(N)-1, r(N)-1, 0.975)


    foreach v of local exog {
        
        local ++i   
        
        /* Calculate stats for varlist */
        qui sum `v' if _treated==1 
        scalar m1u = r(mean)
        scalar v1u = r(Var)
        mat A[`i',1] = r(mean)
        
        qui sum `v' if _treated==0 
        scalar m0u = r(mean)
        scalar v0u = r(Var)
        mat A[`i',2] = r(mean)
        
        qui sum `v' [iw=_weight] if _treated==1 & _support==1 & esample==1
        scalar m1m = r(mean)
        scalar v1m = r(Var)
        mat A[`i',3] = r(mean)
        
        qui sum `v'  if _treated==0 & _support==1 & esample==1
        scalar m0m = r(mean)
        scalar v0m = r(Var)
        mat A[`i',4] = r(mean)
            
        /* Get Var ratio */
        scalar v_ratiobef = v1u/v0u
        scalar v_ratioaft = v1m/v0m
        mat A[`i',12] = v1u/v0u
        mat A[`i',13] = v1m/v0m     
        
        /* Get Var ratio */
        capture assert `v'==0 | `v'==1 | `v'==., fast
        if (_rc) {
            local cont_cnt = `cont_cnt' +1
            
            scalar v_ratiobef = v1u/v0u 
            if v_ratiobef>Fhighu  | v_ratiobef<Flowu {
                local cont_varbef = `cont_varbef' +1
            }
            
            scalar v_ratioaft = v1m/v0m
            if v_ratioaft>Fhighm  | v_ratioaft<Flowm {
                local cont_varaft = `cont_varaft' +1
            }
        }
        
        /* Standardised bias before matching */
        scalar bias = 100*(m1u - m0u)/sqrt((v1u + v0u)/2)
        mat A[`i',5] = bias
        
        qui replace _bias0 = bias in `i'
        qui replace sumbias0 = abs(bias) in `i'
        
        /* Standardised bias after matching */
        scalar biasm = 100*(m1m - m0m)/sqrt((v1u + v0u)/2)
        mat A[`i',6] = biasm
        
        qui replace _biasm = biasm in `i'
        qui replace sumbias = abs(biasm) in `i'
        
        /* Reduction in absolute bias */
        mat A[`i',7] = -100*(abs(biasm) - abs(bias))/abs(bias)
            
        /* t-tests before matching */
        qui regress `v' _treated 
        mat A[`i',8] = _b[_treated]/_se[_treated]
        mat A[`i',9] = 2*ttail(e(df_r),abs(_b[_treated]/_se[_treated]))

        /* t-tests after matching */
        qui regress `v' _treated [iw=_weight] if _support==1 & esample==1
        mat A[`i',10] = _b[_treated]/_se[_treated]  //taft
        mat A[`i',11] = 2*ttail(e(df_r),abs(_b[_treated]/_se[_treated]))  //paft
        
            scalar vrb = 100*`cont_varbef'/`cont_cnt'
            scalar vra = 100*`cont_varaft'/`cont_cnt'

}

    /* Get overall stats for the second table */
    qui probit _treated `exog' if esample==1
    qui predict double index0 if e(sample), xb

    mat R[1,1] = e(r2_p) // r2bef
    mat R[1,3] = e(chi2) // chibef new
    mat R[1,5] = chi2tail(e(df_m), e(chi2)) // probbef
    
    qui probit _treated `exog' [iw=_weight] if _support==1 & esample==1
    qui predict double indexm if e(sample), xb
    mat R[1,2] = e(r2_p) // r2aft 
    mat R[1,4] = e(chi2) // chibef 
    mat R[1,6] = chi2tail(e(df_m), e(chi2))  //probaft 

    qui replace _bias0 = bias in `i'
    qui replace sumbias0 = abs(bias) in `i'
    
    qui replace _biasm = biasm in `i'
    qui replace sumbias = abs(biasm) in `i'
    
    qui sum sumbias0, detail
    mat R[1,7] = r(mean) // meanbiasbef 
    mat R[1,9] = r(p50) // medbiasbef  
    
    qui sum sumbias, detail
    mat R[1,8] = r(mean) // meanbiasaft 
    mat R[1,10] = r(p50) // medbiasaft 
        
    qui sum index0 if _treated==1 & esample==1
    scalar mi1 = r(mean) 
    scalar vi1 = r(Var)
    qui sum index0 if _treated==0 & esample==1
    scalar mi0 = r(mean)
    scalar vi0 = r(Var)
    mat R[1,11] = 100*(mi1 - mi0)/sqrt((vi1 + vi0)/2) // ibiasbef
    mat R[1,13] = vi1/vi0 // iratiobef

    qui sum indexm [iw=_weight] if _treated==1 & _support==1 & esample==1
    scalar mi1 = r(mean) 
    scalar vi1 = r(Var)
    qui sum indexm [iw=_weight] if _treated==0 & _support==1 & esample==1
    scalar mi0 = r(mean)
    scalar vi0 = r(Var)
    mat R[1,12] = 100*(mi1 - mi0)/sqrt((vi1 + vi0)/2) // ibiasaft
    mat R[1,14] = vi1/vi0 // iratioaft
    
    mat R[1,15] = 100*`cont_varbef'/`cont_cnt'
    mat R[1,16] = 100*`cont_varaft'/`cont_cnt'
    
end 

* Get example dataset
webuse cattaneo2, clear 

* Keep only the used variables
keep mbsmoke foreign alcohol mage medu fage fedu bweight

* Run psmatch2
qui psmatch2 mbsmoke foreign alcohol mage medu fage fedu, out(bweight) logit n(5) ai(5) ate common
qui gen esample=e(sample)

mat P=J(1,13,.)
local xvars foreign alcohol mage medu fage fedu
pstest_tables "`xvars'" "`r(atu)'"

* Run the pstest_tables function
qui psmatch2 mbsmoke foreign alcohol mage medu fage fedu, out(bweight) logit n(5) ai(5) ate common
pstest, both atu
mat li A
mat li R

matrix colnames R = "R2(U)" "R2(M)" "LRchi2(U)" "p>chi2(U)" "MeanBias(U)" "MedBias(U)" "B(U)" ///
"R(U)" "%Var(U)" "LRchi2(M)" "p>chi2(M)" "MeanBias(M)" "MedBias(M)" "B(M)" "R(M)" "%Var(M)"

* Reshape the matrix to resemble the tables from pstest
mat B = A[1..6,1..4]
mata : M = colshape(st_matrix("B"),2)
mata : st_matrix("B",M)

mat C = A[1..6,5..6]
mata:  M = colshape(st_matrix("C"),1)
mata : st_matrix("C",M)

mat D = J(12,1,.)
mat D[2,1] = A[1,7]
mat D[4,1] = A[2,7]
mat D[6,1] = A[3,7]
mat D[8,1] = A[4,7]
mat D[10,1] = A[5,7]
mat D[12,1] = A[6,7]

mat E = A[1..6,8..11] 
mata: M = colshape(st_matrix("E"),2)
mata : st_matrix("E",M)

mat F = A[1..6,12..13] 
mata: M = colshape(st_matrix("F"),1)
mata : st_matrix("F",M)

mat G = B,C,D,E,F

mata: M = colshape(st_matrix("R"),2)
mata: st_matrix("R",M)
mat R = R'
mat li R

matrix colnames R = "Ps R2" "LR chi2" "p>chi2" "MeanBias" "MedBias" "B" "R" "%Var" 
matrix rownames R = "Unmatched" "Matched"

matrix colnames G = "Treated" "Control" "%bias" "%red_bias" "t" "p>|t|" "V(T)/V(C)" 
matrix rownames G = "foreign (U)" "foreign (M)" "alcohol (U)" "alcohol (M)" "mage (U)" /// 
"mage (M)" "medu (U)" "medu (M)" "fage (U)" "fage (M)" "fedu (U)" "fedu (M)"
estout mat(G, fmt(3))
mat li R, format(%4.3f)

qui psmatch2 mbsmoke foreign alcohol mage medu fage fedu, out(bweight) logit n(5) ai(5) ate common
pstest, both atu
```

Comment: "I would suggest that Stata consider requiring authors of packages to make any output to the screen retrieveable by using return list or ereturn list"   This is not going to happen. First of all, many commands are not r-class or e-class and should not be. Second, the notion of prohibiting or inhibiting code that you think is poor is dubious for a long list of reasons.  That said, it is indeed good practice to save results that a user might want to retrieve.

Comment: You're in effect asking for a code review.  Your code looks careful, but is very long by SO standards. It would be your good fortune if someone were to read it and give you comments.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. - I've revised my post to clarify. On your first point, I agree about r and e-class commands. I'd be happy to retrieve the information from memory in any form rather than copying and pasting. Second, my suggestion does not imply "prohibiting or inhibiting code" in any way, and I did not refer to the code in pstest as "poor" or "dubious." On the contrary, I think `pstest' has some great attributes, which appear to be strengthened in flexpaneldid. My suggestion reflects my thoughts on how packages can be more user-friendly. Finally, I did not ask for a code review. - Michael Willox

Comment: Your suggestion was that "Stata consider requiring" and it was this suggestion that I consider a non-starter.  Sorry, but regardless of what wording you prefer there is too much code here to think through in my view and one person upvoted that comment. Surely, if someone has a different view, they will answer your question.

Comment: This question seems to be too broad to fit the scope of Stack Overflow. I'm not sure I understand what you need. You want different code, but are not looking for edits?

Comment: I apologize if I’ve given too much detail. To put it simply, if you run the code below, you will see that the output in the first table can only be retrieved for later use by copying and pasting. 

`webuse cattaneo2, clear`
`qui psmatch2 mbsmoke foreign alcohol mage medu fage fedu, out(bweight) logit n(5) ai(5) ate common`
`pstest, both atu`

You’re right that the length of my code is a problem, but I’ve found no other. There are no responses to the post that I linked on StataList (see “elsewhere,” third sentence of my post). Something using putdocx, for example, would be great.

Comment: Perhaps “Stata could recommend best practices” for the creators of packages that allow users to save their output would work better. Regardless, packages that necessitate developing a workaround to save results are a problem.

Comment: Have you approached the program author?

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using some matching techniques and had the same question. One shortcut I found is using 'asdoc'.

I used:
"asdoc pstest v1 v2 v3"

asdoc created a word document called myfile in your working directory and from there you might take the table and transform into latex maybe. I haven't found a better way yet, but thought if it comes handy to you somehow.
Good luck with your work! :)

Answer (score 0):

`asdoc` lacks a dedicated module for processing the `pstest` table. Consequently, it writes the `pstest` results to a log file and then converts that log into a table. While this table contains all the necessary information, its structure and formatting may not be ideal.

To address this limitation, I developed a specific module for `pstest` within `asdocx`, the premium version of `asdoc`. For those interested, they may like to visit the [pstest page on the asdocx website](https://asdocx.com/export-pstest-table-from-stata-to-word-excel-latex-with-asdocx/).